# Can you configure TypeScript to treat all files independently?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript provides editor functionality across a project. Is it possible to disable this? I’d like my editor / TypeScript to treat all files within my project separately, unless I explicitly import one from another.

Comment: Can you please share an example? Because if all files are modules, they don't share scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "independently"? What behaviors exactly are you trying to prevent?